# how to use dustjs-linkedin as client side templating?

Tags: node.js, dust.js, client-side-templating

I get the idea of server and client side templating, but dust.js confuses me a little bit.

In order to use dust.js for client side templating, you need three steps:

1. complie the template
2. load the template
3. render the template

Right?

But where do the templates come from? I saw two different methods:

```
 1. <script> template <script>
 2. <div> template </div>
```

... Both of them are in the DOM. Which is correct?

I also notice that you can load the template via ajax, so the template won't be seen in the DOM, but I don't know how to do that.

Also, I'm currently using jade as express view engine. Is it necessary to switch to dust.js? What is the advantage?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is LinkedIn Dust JS wiki page that can answer your questions and has very good examples: http://linkedin.github.com/dustjs/

But to answer your questions here:

Yes you need to compile your dust template which becomes a JavaScript file that you can add to your page by `<script>` tag and then call **dust.render** method to render your template. Here is an example:

1. write following code in a template file and save it as **sample.tl**

   ```
   <p>Hi {firstName} {lastName}</p>
   ```
2. compile sample.tl to sample.js by `dustc sample.tl` in command line or use `dust.compile("your_template_code", "template_name")` to compile the template and save the output in a JavaScript file (sample.js) or you use duster.js to watch and compile templates by nodejs: https://github.com/dmix/dusterjs
3. add sample.js in your html:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="sample.js"></script>
   ```

   this will also register your template to dust.cache.
4. in your JavaScript:

   ```
   var your_json = {firstName:'James', lastName:'Smith'};

   dust.render('sample', your_json, function(err, out){

       your_dom_element.innerHTML = out;

   });
   ```

   The result of above `dust.render` method will be **`<p>Hi James Smith</p>`**

   So you need to pass 3 arguments to `dust.render`: `dust.render(template_name, json, callback)`

Comment: I'm using linkedin-dust and express, how do I get access to dust.render on the client side? I presume I have to include a js file however do I have to manually add its as statically severed content or  does dust include a request handler for the file?

Comment: Yes you need to add dust-core.js to your page in order to render a dust template. You also need to add the compiled dust templates files. https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/blob/master/dist/dust-core.js

Answer (score 0):

As the wiki say, you can use dust in the client or in the server. If you use it in the client you should get the template (for example with an ajax request), compile it an render in the browser. You will have to include the dust scripts file in your page.

By the other hand you can use dust in the server, (using rhino or nodejs). In this case you are going to compile and render the template in the server so the browser will receive html.

Comment: By the way, this is poor advice if you are interested in performance. It is much better if your templates do not change, to compile them once and then serve the compiled templates directly to the client, rather than to compile them client-side. That way you don't need to send dust.js to the client, and the client doesn't need to spend time compiling your templates.

Comment: It's best to precompile on build or as part of development, and then compile with the model on the client. This way you can allow for local caching of your templates.