# how to use dust partial template files (.tl files)

Tags: dust.js

I have few questions on partials and overriding templates.
For that i used the following folder structure.

**projectRoot**

```
   dust-core-0.6.0.min.js
   jquery.js
   test.html
   partial.tl
   main_without_override.tl
```

The content of `partial.tl:`

```
{+greeting} Hola {/greeting}

{+world} World {/world}
```

The content of `main_without_override.tl`:

```
{>partial/}
```

The content of `test.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="dust-core-0.6.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jq.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
  <script>
    $.get('main_without_override.tl', function(){
        console.log(arguments);
    })
  </script>
</html>
```

In the `index.html` when i try to get the `main_without_override.tl` its saying 404. But im sure that the file is there. The path that firebug is showing is correct.But browser says 404.

I want to know

1. How to get this `main_without_override.tl`
2. Apply templating for `main_without_override.tl` and render in the browser.

I searched in google most of the examples give only the syntax. Can somebody help me in rendering the `main_without_override.tl` template.

Comment: u have to add more info. why are u trying to get the partial with a request? what are you using as server? what is the request path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include your dust template as a JavaScript file by using `<script>` tag, but you need to compile it first, which is explained **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13736462/how-to-use-dustjs-linkedin-as-client-side-templating/13854510)**

Then add following templates (scripts) to `test.html`:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="partial.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main_without_override.js"></script>
```

And in you JavaScript render the template by `dust.render` method:

```
    dust.render('main_without_override', your_json_object, function(err, out){

        your_dom_element.innerHTML = out;

    });
```

Related question:
[how to use dustjs-linkedin as client side templating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13736462/how-to-use-dustjs-linkedin-as-client-side-templating/13854510)

Comment: This answered my question. Can you also let me know if its possible to get `.tl` files through ajax. I'm getting `404` error while trying to get '.tl` files. From the dust js site i came to know that if i need to compile the templates in browser in need to include a complier js. I included the complier script, by doing so i get an js error `AST.parse` is not a function. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Are you trying to do this using a file: protocol?  You must use http:

Answer (score 1):

In order to compile templates on the client (which is probably not a really good idea), you need to include `dust-full` instead of `dust-core`. This is because `dust-core` does not include the Dust compiler.

The reason that compiling templates on the client is probably not a good idea is that Dust compiles to JavaScript and as @monshi mentioned, you can compile the templates and then serve them as JavaScript. It is possible to get `.tl` files through AJAX if you include `dust-full`, but it is a better idea to compile that template beforehand and then make a dynamic request for that `.js` file when you need.