# how to write some variable(name and value) in dust template using helper

Tags: dust.js

I have client side dust template and a corresponding helper.

Helper :

```
function(chunk, context, bodies, params) {
};
```

Now I want to write some key value pair(from helper) which I can read in dust template.
e.g.If i write (k,v) in helper, in dust template

```
{k}
```

should output 'v'

Thanks,
Shantanu

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21356235/basic-example-of-client-side-templating-with-dust-js

This can help you check things!!

Answer (score 1):

A helper in Dust receives the current `chunk` and `context`. You can push new values onto the context stack, and then call `chunk.render()`.

```
{
  "helper": function(chunk, context, bodies, params) {
    var obj = { "k": "value" };
    return chunk.render(bodies.block, context.push(obj));
  }
}
```

Here, I am rendering the default body (`bodies.block`), using the existing context as well as my extra `obj`, which is pushed onto the context stack.

```
{#helper}{k}{/helper} {! k is only accessible inside the context of my helper !}
```